# Hi, How can I convert iTunes M4V to Mov? I try multiple free online software, but none of them work

Tags: video

How can I convert iTunes M4V to Mov? I try multiple free online software, but none of them work

Comment: Why do you need to bother?  M4V support is pretty universal and both are simply containers for a video stream, so it doesn't seem particularly likely to help to simply change the container if you are having a problem with a particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

> M4V is a file extension for a container file defined in the systems
>   part of the MPEG-4 standard (ISO 14496-1), as downloaded by iTunes. An
>   M4V file can be renamed to the more common extension of MP4 to be
>   played on other media players if not protected content.

As mp4 and mov almost same, just rename it to mov